# android- How to solve the no resource found

Tags: android, styles

I implemented the one application in one system and in this i am using the different styles. it works properly. But the same application code is running in the different system then i am getting the following error.

**Error:** Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.RatingBar.Small'.

How to solve this error. please can anybody help me.I used the following code for style.

**Style:**

```
<style name="reviewRatingBar2" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar" >
 <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/review_rating_bar_full_2</item>
 <item name="android:minHeight">17dip</item>
 <item name="android:maxHeight">17dip</item></style> 
 <style name="reviewRatingBar3" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar.Small" >
 <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/review_rating_bar_full_2</item>
 <item name="android:minHeight">17dip</item>
 <item name="android:maxHeight">17dip</item></style>
```

Comment: are you using different api versions in the two projects?

Comment: No. I am using the same api versions (i.e, Android2.2)

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, the device is missing that resource. You could extract it from your_android_sdk_install/platforms/android-8/data/res/values/styles.xml and place it in your styles.xml, ensuring it is constant on all devices.

Perhaps that resource was included in 2.2, but the device that generates the error is only running 2.1 or some such?

Comment: Actually in my app there is no styles.xml file. So the code inside of the style.xml file is pasted in the string.xml(under the Style tag) file. is it fine? or can i past the styles.xml file in the values folder of my app?

Comment: Create a new file called styles.xml in ur_app/res/values and copy and paste the specific missing style from the sdk styles.xml file (or probably don't want to copy all of it).